# .htaccess mod_rewrite to hide querystring variables into fake pathinfo

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

New to mod_rewrite under a subdirectory-esque structure.  Specifically, would like to display URLs formatted like this:

```
http://www.oursite.com/signup/?key=xyzabc
```

to this:

```
http://www.oursite.com/signup/xyzabc
```

Anyone have a quick snippet for accomplishing this?  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^signup/([a-z]*)/?$ signup/?key=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Will do it. All time favorit is the mod_rewrite [cheat sheet v2](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/).

Comment: But it'll visually redirect.
How to redirect, so user can't see the real URL?

Comment: @Jeff_Alieffson What do you mean by this. Can you give an example of the origin url and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Just going off of memory:

```
RewriteRule ^/signup/?key=(.*)$ /signup/$1 [L]
```